# Flask app missing gunicorn-cfg file after docker build

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have dockerized flask app and I am trying to setup it for changing some html files without rebuilding docker each time change is made.

I have made volumes for my app, here is docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appseed-app:
    container_name: appseed_app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./server:/home/user/webapp/aap
    build: .
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web_network
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "5085:5085"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web_network
    depends_on: 
      - appseed-app
networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
```

and docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_APP run.py
ENV DEBUG True

COPY requirements.txt .

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY env.sample .env

# gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "run:app"]
```

When building i get error: `gunicorn-cfg.py file doesn't exist`

I tried to change gunicorn CMD to point to complete path to gunicorn-cfg.py file but no luck.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never copy a file named `gunicorn-cfg.py` into your image. You only copy `requirements.txt` and `env.sample`.